# Nestjs how to make extend partialtype(createDto) make nested properties of dtos inside createDto also optional

Tags: nestjs

I have UpdateUserDto:

```
export class UpdateUserDto extends PartialType(CreateUserDto) {

}
```

CreateUserDto:

```
export class CreateUserDto {
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @IsOptional()
  Point: CreateUserPointDto;
}
```

CreateUserPointDto:

```
 export class CreateUserPointDto{
  @IsString()
  name: string
  @IsString()
  color: string
  
}
```

Now partial type makes all properties of CreateUserDto optional, the problem is, it doesn't create all properties of Point that is inside CreateUserDto optional.

How do I go about solving this issue?

Also another unrelated problem, any validation to Point in UpdateUser only works with `{ PartialType } from '@nestjs/mapped-types'`

If I use `import { PartialType } from '@nestjs/swagger'`, For the same code it says Point.property name/color should not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you may have moved on from this, but here's something that may resolve the issue in case you come around in the future.

You need to use [`@Type`](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#working-with-nested-objects) from [`class-transformers`](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) to ensure you get the types for the nested `Point` attribute.

#### Sample code

```js
import { Type } from 'class-transformer';

export class CreateUserDto {
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @IsOptional()

  @Type(() => CreateUserPointDto) // -> this line
  Point: CreateUserPointDto;
}
```

Comment: Haven't coded in NestJS in a while but If I remember correctly what you said is correct, so thanks hopefully that will help others!

Comment: This does not work for nested Property as it still check for all the property of CreateUserPointDto

Answer (score 0):

You can create a partial type for `CreateUserPointDto`:

```
export class UpdateCreateUserPointDto extends PartialType(CreateUserPointDto) {}
```

And `UpdateUserDto` will be then:

```
export class UpdateUserDto extends PartialType(CreateUserDto) {
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @IsOptional()
  @Type(() => UpdateCreateUserPointDto)
  Point?: CreateUserPointDto;
}
```