# NestJS Open API nested DTOs and PartialType

Tags: nestjs, openapi, nestjs-swagger

I have a setup like this:

```js
export class RequestDTO {
  @ApiProperty()
  mainObj: MainObjDTO;
}

export class MainObjDTO {
  @ApiProperty()
  latLong: LatLongDTO
}

export class LatLongDTO {
  @ApiProperty()
  lat: string;

  @ApiProperty()
  long: string;  
}
```

When updating MainObj I have something like:

```js
class PartialMainObjDTO extends PartialType(
  MainObjDTO,
) {}

export class UpdateRequestDTO {
  @ApiProperty()
  mainObj: PartialMainObjDTO;
}
```

The problem is that `latLong` is still marked as required during Update.

Is it possible to have a 'deep' PartialType somehow?

Comment: Is it that `latLong` is marked as required or is it that once you send ` latLog: { lat: somethign }` `latLong.long` is then required?

Comment: I believe the default is that it's required.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67695710/nestjs-how-to-make-extend-partialtypecreatedto-make-nested-properties-of-dtos)

Answer (score -2):

Is your `PartialType` imported from `@nestjs/swagger`?

[@Nestjs/swagger mapped-types](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/mapped-types)

```js
import { PartialType } from '@nestjs/swagger'
```

Comment: The import is there.